# my entities are no longer exposed on API PLATFORM after upgrading

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I just upgraded API platform to version 3.0.
After the few classical modifications linked to the version upgrade, and despite the use of: `php bin/console api:upgrade-resource`

I notice that my entities are not exposed anymore when I go to the API documentation and if I try to access an endpoint, I get a route error:
No route found for "GET https://127.0.0.1:9000/api/XXX

I replaced all the ApiResource uses in my entities and rewrote my annotations.

example of an entity:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Test;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
#[ApiResource(

collectionOperations: [
    'get',
    'post' => [
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['create:xxx']]
    ]
],
    itemOperations: [
    'get' => [
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['read:fully:xxx']]
    ],
    'put' => [
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['update:xxx']]
    ],
    'delete'
],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:xxx']]

)]

class Departement
{
....
}
```

Thanks in advance!

ok so, i update a little entity manually and now she is exposed !

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Agorha;

//use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\Entity\ChoixEcole;
use App\Repository\Agorha\EcoleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EcoleRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "agorha_ecole")]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()]

#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(),
    new GetCollection()
])]
#[
    UniqueEntity('code')
]
class Ecole
{
    #[ORM\Id()]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue()]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private $id;
```

i didn't see the results of the upgrade command, which ended up being an error and therefore did nothing.
in fact, it does not seem to exist

```
 Command "api:upgrade-resource" is not defined.
```

anyone would know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your entities are still in the <= v2.6 format despite your call to the `api:upgrade-resource` command.

See the [migration documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/upgrade-guide/#apiresource-metadata): instead of
`'get'`, `'post'`, etc. you should use new Metadata classes `Get()`, `Post()`, etc.

Are you sure that the migration command returned no error?
In my case (migration from 2.6 to 3.0) the migration command was not available for unknwon reason (not found from the console).

Try migrating manually one entity to the new format and watch your openApi documentation to see if your endpoints are back.

**Edit:** Why didn't `api:upgrade-resource` work ?

As far as I understand, the migration command is provided in v2.7 to prepare migration to 3.0 but has been dropped from v3.0. So the proper way to migrate according to the doc is:

1. migrate to 2.7
2. call `api:upgrade-resource` and check all is working
3. THEN migrate to 3.0

Comment: Can you update your post and publish your new Entity class so I can try to guess the problem? (but keep also your original code to help users to get the context)

Comment: Hello and thx for your answer.
After checking, it seems that the upgrade command did not work properly.
I have just manually modified one of my entities to fit the new 'Metadata' mode.

Unfortunately no change, and my entities are still not exposed on my doc.

Comment: Ok, seems good. Can you post the result of `bin/console debug:route` and the content of `config/packages/api_platform.yaml`? On one similar migration I had a problem with a routePrefix parameter which masked all my api routes

Comment: Nice, so updating the entity manually worked!
As far as I understand, the migration command is provided in v2.7 to prepare migration to 3.0 but has been dropped from v3.0. So the proper way to migrate would porbably be:
1) migrate to 2.7
2) call `api:upgrade-resource` and check all is working
3) THEN migrate to 3.0
Documentation states you should call migration command from v2.7 but doesn't say clearly it won't work from 3.0

Comment: Oh OK, thanks for the information.
so i ll manually update my entities.
thx again !

Answer (score 0):

like @MendelYev says i should run the api upgrade command before upgrade.
now i ve to upgrade manually my entities using PHP attributes and new Metadata classes from Doctrine

Comment: if it helped you out then you should accept MendelYev's answer as correct and assign him the points.  You can do this by clicking the checkbox.